# What is the class of mail the IRS uses to return the original documents submitted for an ITIN application?

Tags: united-states, irs, itin, mailing

Did anyone get their passport back from IRS for their ITIN W7 application along with their I-1040? If yes, I'd like to know the mail class they used to return the document. The IRS site says the original document will be returned through "postage paid standard US mail". We did a change of address and I was hoping the mail forwarding would work for the original documents as well. I tried to follow up with the IRS but I'm also trying to learn what might have happened and why the mail didn't forward to my new address. I did receive my ITIN through mail forwarding. I'm hoping that they sent my passport by a mail class that has a tracking ability.

I like to hear from people who received their original document.

Answer (score 3):

According to IRS document (http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/iw7.pdf)

> Original documents you submit will be returned to you
>   at the mailing address shown on your Form W-7. **You
>   do not need to provide a return envelope. Applicants
>   are permitted to include a prepaid Express Mail or courier
>   envelope for faster return delivery of their documents.** The IRS
>   will then return the documents in the envelope provided by the
>   applicant.

***emphasis is mine**

This would suggest that unless you provide a different mailing option to them, they will return to you via the standard USPS First Class Mail (although probably metered for them).